# how to send LocalDateTime.now() in java to the database (without sending a date from the frontend)?

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring-boot

the table contains this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Embeddable
public class SourceContentMappingPK implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "hr_code")
    private String hrCode;

    @Column(name = "muse_id")
    private String museId;

    @Column(name = "source_type")
    private String sourceType;

    @Column(name = "cts")
    private LocalDateTime cts;
}
```

This is the model:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class SourceContentMappingDTO {
    private String hrCode;
    private String museId;
    private String sourceType;
    private String masterHotelId;
    private LocalDateTime cts;

    public SourceContentMappingDTO(String hrCode, String museId, String sourceType, String masterHotelId, LocalDateTime cts) {
        this.hrCode = hrCode;
        this.museId = museId;
        this.sourceType = sourceType;
        this.masterHotelId = masterHotelId;
        this.cts = cts;
    }
}
```

When I send a request through postman, the current date and time are written to the database. When I make the same request through the page, everything except the date is written to the database. It is necessary to enter the date without sending it from the frontend.

```
 @Override
    @Transactional
    public void updateImageSources(HotelMasterListSubItemDTO dto) {
        dto.setContentSources(Arrays.asList("IMAGES"));

        List<SourceContentMapping> sourceContentMappings = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select * from SOURCE_CONTENT_MAPPING where master_hotel_id = :masterHotelId", SourceContentMapping.class)
                .setParameter("masterHotelId", dto.getMasterHotelId())
                .setHint(QueryHints.READ_ONLY, true)
                .getResultList();

        for(String contentSourceType : dto.getContentSources()) {
            boolean contentSourceTypeExists = false;
            for(SourceContentMapping sourceContentMapping : sourceContentMappings) {
                if(contentSourceType.equals(sourceContentMapping.getId().getSourceType())) {
                    contentSourceTypeExists = true;

                    entityManager.createNativeQuery("update SOURCE_CONTENT_MAPPING set muse_id = :museId, hr_code = :hrCode, cts = :cts where master_hotel_id = :masterHotelId and source_type = :sourceType")
                            .setParameter("museId", dto.getMuseId())
                            .setParameter("hrCode", dto.getHrCode())
                            .setParameter("masterHotelId", dto.getMasterHotelId())
                            .setParameter("sourceType", contentSourceType)
                            .setParameter("cts", LocalDateTime.now())
                            .executeUpdate();
                }
            }

            if(!contentSourceTypeExists) {
                entityManager.createNativeQuery("insert into SOURCE_CONTENT_MAPPING (hr_code, muse_id, source_type, master_hotel_id, cts) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")
                        .setParameter(1, dto.getHrCode())
                        .setParameter(2, dto.getMuseId())
                        .setParameter(3, contentSourceType)
                        .setParameter(4, dto.getMasterHotelId())
                        .setParameter(5, LocalDateTime.now())
                        .executeUpdate();
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried adding .setParameter ("cts", LocalDateTime.now ()) and .setParameter (5, LocalDateTime.now ()) but like I said only through postman it works but not through GUI. I need to make the parameter optional, nullable e.g.

Using MySQL. Table contains:

```
museId (varchar 50, notNull),
  hrCode (varchar 50, notNull),
  source_type (varchar 50, notNull),
  masterHotelId (varchar 100),
  cts (timestamp)
  …
```

[At this link is a picture: The first record in the database was sent from the postman, and the second is through the page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVwyN.png)

Comment: Well, you say "not through GUI". What kind of GUI?

Comment: What is the database table defined like? And which brand of database engine are you using?

Comment: @MCEmperor It doesn't work for me through the page where I need to add the date of execution of a certain work.

Comment: @OleV.V. using MySql, and table contains: museId (varchar 50, notNull), hrCode (varchar 50, notNull), source_type (varchar 50, notNull), masterHotelId (varchar 100), cts (timestamp)

Comment: I believe that a MySQL `timestamp` is always in UTC. You may try `OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)` or even `Instant.now()`. I haven’t tried myself; they are just the next things I would try if it were me.

Comment: Also which version of Spring Boot are you using? Is it true that your Spring Boot uses Hibernate, and if so, do you know which version? If I recall correctly, Hibernate doesn’t support java.time types until version 5 (hope I’m wrong).

Comment: @OleV.V. Spring Boot <version>2.7.0-M1</version>, and  Spring B. uses Hibernate

Comment: @OleV.V.  btw. i have tried all these suggestions but for all only the date is entered when the request is sent through postman but not through the page.

Answer (score 0):

To get timestamp value and put it to sql you can simply use #Timestamp.valueOf() method and put your LocalDateTime to the method`s param. To get time you can use = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()) on backend side

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. That’s a step backward. The `Timestamp` class is poorly designed and long outdated. We should use classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) exclusively.

Comment: JDBC 4.2 or higher compliant drivers should support `java.time.LocalDateTime` for the same datatypes that they support `java.sql.Timestamp`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Is that exactly true? For a standard SQL `timestamp with time zone` I believe a `java.sql.Timestamp` was accepted, but today an `OffsetDateTime` is needed, only some drivers sensibly also accept `Instant`. Asking so becuase I have understood that MySQL does its best to keep a `timestamp` in UTC, that is, it behaves pretty much like a `timestamp with time zone` in many other database brands.

Comment: @OleV.V. No, JDBC only defines `OffsetDateTime` for `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. Some drivers will offer more flexibility, sometimes for historic reasons, but such a mapping is technically not compliant (or at least, non-standard). See also appendix B of JDBC 4.2 or 4.3. JDBC doesn't even define support for `java.time.Instant`, the only occurrence is in `java.sql.Timestamp` (`toInstant()`, `from(Instant)`), and then only because `java.util.Date` already defines it.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel So far it agrees with my understanding. So the question is which JDBC type MySQL’s `timestamp` maps to. If to JDBC `timestamp`, then we’re on the wrong track for explaining the OP’s problem.

Answer (score 0):

## Wrong data types

You are incorrectly mixing the wrong data types.

See the [MySQL 8 documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html).

See also Comments on the Question by Ole V.V.

### Moment

The `TIMESTAMP` type in MySQL 8 is akin to the SQL standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. Use this type to record a moment, a specific point on the timeline. This type represents date with time-of-day as seen “in UTC”, an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. The matching type in Java is `OffsetDateTime`, as specified by the JDBC spec.

### Not a moment

The `DATETIME` type in MySQL 8 is akin to the SQL standard type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`. This type represents a date with time of day, but lacks the context of a time zone or offset from UTC. **This type cannot represent a moment.** The matching Java type is `LocalDateTime`.

So your use of Java `LocalDateTime` with MySQL `TIMESTAMP` is a mismatch. Indeed, I cannot imagine a scenario where calling `LocalDateTime.now` is the right thing to do.

You have not explained your business domain. So I cannot advise you on which type is appropriate. But I can tell you to not mix the wrong types together.

## Avoid legacy date-time types

Never use the classes `java.sql.Timestamp`, `Calendar`, or either `Date`. These are terribly flawed in design.

Those classes are now legacy,  years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.